# Illustrator file size PDF vs JPEG export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, jpg, file-size

I've come across a weird behavior regarding the output file size when exporting/saving files from Illustrator CC.

I have an image with several bitmaps (i.e. raster images/photographs) where I added some annotations, markings, paths, etc. The photograph occupies the whole artboard (which is set to my desired output size), vector features are therefor only on top of the photographs.

Now when I export this as JPEG the file turns out to be around 10 MB large. However, if I save the image as PDF and select JPEG compression, the image only turns out to be 3.5 MB large.

How can that be? Quality should be the same, detail is set to 300 dpi in both cases. I thought if the PDF embeds the JPEG, it should be more or less the same size, and adding PDF container overhead, the PDF should rather be bigger than the JPEG. How can one explain the ~60% smaller file size?

Comment: Well, most probably the mages themselves aren't actually as big as you think. Any image can occupy any size in a illustrator file and the PDF options save images at whatever DPI they actually occupy or 300 if denser than 300PPI.

Comment: But like I stated I specifically turned on resampling to exactly 300 dpi even in PDF export. Also, the images definitely have a higher resolution than 300 dpi.

Comment: Yes but it does not resamples up only down. So if you have any mistake in your thinking that explains it. Remember theres no DPI in illustrator so if you scale a image its nolonger as dense as you think.

Comment: I thought Illustrator doesn't do any resampling? So, if I load a picture, it might get scaled for display, but the data doesn't change. Especially, if I am just linking pictures instead of embedding. Resampling is only done if exporting to raster file formats. Also, I don't believe it doesn't upsample. Otherwise, how do the file properties of exported files show the possibly higher DPI?

Comment: @TTJ no illustrator does not resample, PDF output does! However, if you rescale your effective DPI does change! Since DPI is dependent on size. Data des not change, but DPI is not a inherent property of a picture, it changes. So if the image is larger in size than originally imported as then the DPI is lower than you think. So there are 3 sources for this 1) your dpi isnt what you think it is. (this is hardly surprising about 80% of people who think they understand DPI/PPI/LPI do not) 2) your image contains a lot of empty space 3) something extra is embedded in image.

Comment: @joojaa Of course ppi is dependant of size. But let's say I put my artboard to 8x8 cm. I make my raster image to fill the whole artboard (just by scaling the image, not cropping). Now if I save as PDF, Illustrator gives me options, including (under tab "Compression") downsampling of bitmap images (so yes, no upsampling). How can I check the actual ppi in the output PDF?

Comment: PDF like illustrator has no PPI! You need to check each subimage separately. You can do this in illustrator or acrobat. If you want to do this in illustrator make sure illustrator editing capabilities are off. Or you will open the original linked files.

Comment: @joojaa I mean to see the ppi of my output. Not the AI or what is embedded in there.

Comment: Yes thats what i said.  Export the PDF, either open in acrobat ask for the resolution of each image or. make sure it has no illustrator editing capability and just select the image. It now tells you what the PPI of each of the output images separately whan you select them. No PDF has no PPI

Comment: PPI of the exported jpegs in PDF file is 300, as expected. So same as the single JPEG export. So, still can't explain the huge file size difference.

Comment: Did you check the compression method

Comment: @joojaa When exporting as PDF? I selected "Automatic (JPEG)" with "Image Quality" set to "Maximum". Bicubic downsampling to 300 ppi.

Comment: When you extract the image its still a jpeg you can still save it as a jpeg at that size, so you should be able to see how dofferent it is. However i i could see the file all of this would have taken less than a minute btw.

Comment: What's the best way to send it? Should I attach it to the post?

Comment: @ttJ i dont know if its best but you cant attach a PDF on stackoverflow

Comment: @joojaahave a look at this .AI-file please: https://we.tl/t-ohZFojwYpH

Comment: @joojaa did u have a chance to look at it yet?

Answer (score 2):

When you push this out as a `.pdf`, all your annotations overlaid over the JPG image are *staying* ***vector*** data, whereas when you push it out as a single unified `.jpg`, all those annotations are being rasterized on the fly, and given that `.jpg` compression is nearest-neighbor, that adds a *lot* of minor areas of difference which have to be encoded and cannot be pushed as 'nearly the same as neighbor' into lossy similarity - so honestly it's not at all surprising - especially if you have a fair amount of text in your annotations - text represents a lot of very tiny areas of difference - which is super-hard to compress - but is quite small as vector data or even retained text data.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I had thought about this myself, so I just removed all the annotations. It makes almost no difference to the file size of the exported JPEG (just a few KB), while the PDF still is vastly smaller. It seems the internal JPEG conversion for embedding in PDF works differently. I am using CMYK for both exports. Any more ideas?

Comment: Wow - that is ***fascinating*** - I've not a *clue* then - I think we should see if we can get @joojaa to weigh in on this thread - he has a programming / dev background and knows far mroe about the back-end stuff than I do - maybe he has a suggestion?

Comment: I'll try to setup a set of sample pictures and attach them.

Comment: see the attached file in the comment to my original question, please.